# adding new rows of data to 2d array and paste it back to worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

After assigning a table with 10 rows and 5 columns of data to an array, I wish to add new rows of data to the array before pasting it back to the same worksheet.

Despite days of googling, I'm still having difficulty grasping the concept of 2d arrays so my code below isn't working as intended.

```
Sub testing_array()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

'transposed array with 10 rows and 5 columns of data
Dim myarray As Variant: myarray = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion)

'increase array to 100 rows, 5 columns
ReDim Preserve myarray(1 To 5, 1 To 100)

'assigning values to 11th row of array
myarray(1, 11) = "A"
myarray(2, 11) = "B"
myarray(3, 11) = "C"
myarray(4, 11) = "D"
myarray(5, 11) = "E"

'undo transposing
myarray = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(myarray)

'resize and paste updated array back to worksheet
ws.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(myarray) + 1).value = Application.Transpose(a)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it in this way, please:

```
Sub testing_array()
 Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

 'transposed array with 10 rows and 5 columns of data
 Dim myarray As Variant: myarray = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion)

 'increase array to 15 rows, 5 columns
 ReDim Preserve myarray(1 To 5, 1 To 15)

 'assigning values to 11th row of array
 myarray(1, 11) = "A"
 myarray(2, 11) = "B"
 myarray(3, 11) = "C"
 myarray(4, 11) = "D"
 myarray(5, 11) = "E"

 'You must drop the array content IN A RANGE EXACTLY RESIZED AS THE ARRAY TO BE USED,
 'in terms of number of rows and columns
 'Because of transposing, the rows and columns are reversed in terms of UBound returns:
 ws.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(myarray, 2), UBound(myarray)).value = Application.Transpose(myarray)
End Sub
```

If something (still) not clear, plese do not hesitate to ask for clarification.

**Edited**:

Pleas, look to the next code, showing how to increase the array rows, WHEN YOU DO NOT KNOW how many rows to be added:

```
Sub testing_array_2()
 Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

 'transposed array with 10 rows and 5 columns of data
 Dim myarray As Variant: myarray = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion)
 
 Dim iRow As Long, jCol As Long, i As Long, k As Long
 iRow = UBound(myarray, 2): jCol = UBound(myarray)
 
 'increase array to all rows, all columns columns, to increase with OTHER 100 rows
 ReDim Preserve myarray(1 To jCol, 1 To iRow + 100)

 'assigning values to i rows of array. It can be done from another reange, NOT KNOWING HOW MANY ROWS IT CONTAINS:
 For i = 1 To 10 ' 10 only like an example
    k = iRow + i 'this is the variable to be used for the final Redim Preserve
    myarray(1, k) = "A" & i
    myarray(2, k) = "B" & i
    myarray(3, k) = "C" & i
    myarray(4, k) = "D" & i
    myarray(5, k) = "E" & i
 Next i
 ReDim Preserve myarray(1 To jCol, 1 To iRow + k)
 
 'You must drop the array content IN A RANGE EXACTLY RESIZED AS THE ARRAY TO BE USED
 'in terms of number of rows and columns
 'Because of transposing, the rows and columns are reversed in terms of UBound returns:
 ws.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(myarray, 2), UBound(myarray)).value = Application.Transpose(myarray)
End Sub
```

Comment: @Randy: I was sure that it works, but I would also like to be sure that you understood why it works in that way... Our purpose here is to learn and make people learning... :)

Comment: Yes, I understood clearly. The part that I had difficulty with was copying back the updated array to the worksheet. Your comments have explained it well for me :)

Comment: @Randy: Usually, for the memory appropriate handling,  it is good to `Redim Preserve` only once, estimating a maximum to never be touched and use a variable with the added elements (rows, columns) to finally `ReDim` according to it. No time right now, but I will create such a more complex example (starting from your code) and I will post it as alternative...

Comment: @Randy: Edited the answer and added another piece of code which should be helpful to better understand the adding process. It can be done in many other ways, but I tried following your initial code, to be understood easier.

Comment: Thanks again for going the extra mile to explain things to me. Just one more minor clarification, what happens if `ReDim Preserve myarray(1 To jCol, 1 To iRow + k)` was left out? The code still works so I assume it has something to do with performance?

Comment: @Randy: The code works, but it will also drop other 100 - (iRow + k) empty rows... You do not see them, but it is not good to waste resources and adapt the array memory size to the necessary dimensions.